# How does filter() in dplyr evaluate what's inside the () in a customized function?

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, tidyeval, non-standard-evaluation

I am trying to write a function that takes two column names and upper and/or lower boundary for each column names, so that that way I can subset the data with column names and boundary of my choice.

Using mtcars as an example, if I want to subset the data by saying I only want rows that has `cyl > 4` and `mpg > 15`, in this case my function would take in two column names `cyl` and `mpg`, also two lower boundary for each column name which are 4 and 15. Of course in the function, I have the choice to assign a upper boundary to it to keep column names(variables) within certain range.

So I came up with something like below, a function which takes two variable names of your choice and upper and/or lower boundaries for each variable.

If I only give an upper or lower boundary for this variable then it would give me anything less than or more than this boundary, if I give the function both upper and lower boundary it gives me back the rows that fall into the range.

```
comb_function<-function(df,var1,var2,var1_lower=NULL,var1_upper=NULL,var2_upper=NULL,var2_lower=NULL){
   var1<-enexpr(var1)
   var2<-enexpr(var2)
 #####for var2,if upper boundary are given by user,do this#####{
    filter1<-expr(`$`(df,!!var2))<=var2_upper
    #for var1, if upper boundary are given by user,do this# {
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))<=var1_upper}
    #for var 1,if lower boundary are given by user, do this#{
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))>=var1_lower}
    #for var1, if both are given by user, do this#{
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))>=var1_lower&expr(`$`(df,!!var1))<=var1_upper}
  }
  #####for var2,if lower boundary are given by user,do this#####{
    filter1<-expr(`$`(df,!!var2))>=var2_lower 
    #for var1,if upper boundary are given by user,do this#{
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))<=var1_upper}
    #for var1,if lower boundary are given by user,do this#{
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))>=var1_lower}
    #if both are given by the user,do this{
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))>=var1_lower&expr(`$`(df,!!var1))<=var1_upper}
  }
  #####for var2,if both are given by user,do this#####{
    filter1<-expr(`$`(df,!!var2))<=var2_upper&expr(`$`(df,!!var2))>=var2_lower
    #for var1,if upper boundary are given by user,do this#{
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))<=var1_upper}
    #for var1,if lower boundary are given by user,do this#{
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))>=var1_lower}
    #if both are given by user, do this#{
      filter2<-expr(`$`(df,!!var1))>=var1_lower&expr(`$`(df,!!var1))<=var1_upper}
  }
   output<-df%>%filter(filter1,filter2)%>%summarise(count=n(),avgcyl=mean(cyl,na.rm=TRUE))
    return(output)
}
```

When I call this function using mtcars as an example

```
final1<-comb_function(df=mtcars,var1=mpg,var2=cyl,var1_lower =15,var2_lower=4,var2_upper=6)
```

I got 0 count and NaN for avgcrl in final1. So when `filter()` evaluates what inside the `()`, it only gets FALSE, no TRUE, I think that's why no rows gets returned.

I have a theory for why this is happening. If I do this:

```
x<-expr(cyl);eval(expr(expr(`$`(mtcars,!!x))<=6))
```

It returns:

```
[1]FALSE
```

which is apparently not what I expected to have. If I do this:

```
eval(expr(`$`(mtcars,!!x)))<=6
```

It returns

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

which is what I want for the `filter()` function inside my function. So I am guessing when `filter()` evaluates what's inside `()`, it automatically put the bracket around the whole expression, just like

```
eval(expr(expr(`$`(mtcars,!!x))<=6))
```

did, which only gives back one FALSE. So if this is really the reason like I expected, how do I let `filter()` know what I really want is for it to evaluate like this:

```
eval(filter1<-expr(`$`(df,!!var2)))<=var2_upper
```

not this:

```
eval(filter1<-expr(`$`(df,!!var2))<=var2_upper)
```

If what I guessed is not what's going on, please help me as well.

Comment: I would recommend simplifying your question as much as possible. The first snippet of code in particular is very complex and hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would highly recommend to stay away from all this quoting and evaluating. The tidy eval framework provides alternative tools that are much easier to work with.

> Using mtcars as an example, if I want to subset the data by saying I only want rows that has `cyl > 4` and `mpg > 15`

A typical wrapper function would look like this:

```
filter2 <- function(data, var1, var2, lower1, lower2) {
  data %>%
    filter(
      {{ var1 }} > .env$lower1,
      {{ var2 }} > .env$lower2
    )
}
```

- With the `{{` operator, we're interpolating the input expressions inside the data context. This means you can supply R code that refers to column names directly.
- With `.env$`, we are asking for the `lower` variables inside the function environment. This means that if the data frame contains columns `lower1` and `lower2`, these won't interfere. Another way of forcing evaluation in the environment is to use `!!`.

```
mtcars %>% filter2(cyl, mpg, 4, 15) %>% head()
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp drat  wt qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.6   16  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.9   17  0  1    4    4
#> 3  21   6  258 110  3.1 3.2   19  1  0    3    1
#> 4  19   8  360 175  3.1 3.4   17  0  0    3    2
#> 5  18   6  225 105  2.8 3.5   20  1  0    3    1
#> 6  19   6  168 123  3.9 3.4   18  1  0    4    4
```

================================

The rest of this answer tries to unpack some of the puzzles you brought up. This might be useful to get a better sense of the evaluation model in R, but again you're better off finding simpler approaches to solving your issues.

Let's take:

```
x<-expr(cyl);eval(expr(expr(`$`(mtcars,!!x))<=6))
#> [1] FALSE
```

Reformatting a bit:

```
x <- expr(cyl)
eval(expr(expr(`$`(mtcars,!!x)) <= 6))
```

Removing the unnecessary complexity:

```
eval(expr(expr(mtcars$cyl) <= 6))
```

Let's look at the intermediate result:

```
expr(expr(mtcars$cyl) <= 6)
#> expr(mtcars$cyl) <= 6
```

The outer `expr()` returns an expression instructing R to:

1. Create a new expression (with the inner `expr()`)
2. Compare that expression to `6`

Unfortunately, R expressions are comparable even though it doesn't make any sense. In an ideal world this would be an error:

```
quote(foo) < 10
#> [1] FALSE
```

Probably what you'd like to do is to compute the column subsetting described in the expression first, and then compare with `<=`:

```
eval(expr(mtcars$cyl)) <= 6
#>  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [11]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [21]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> [31] FALSE  TRUE
```

Another note. You write:

```
eval(filter1<-expr(`$`(df,!!var2)))
```

Reformatting and simplifying:

```
eval(filter1 <- expr(mtcars$cyl)))
```

Here's what's happening when you evaluate this:

1. `eval()` asks R to return its first argument, so it can evaluate it.
2. R sees that the argument to `eval()` is a `<-` call. It then starts to evaluate it.
3. The RHS is a defused expression describing how to subset `mtcars`. This RHS is assigned to the LHS `filter1`.
4. `<-` returns the RHS, invisibly. This is what `eval()` gets as argument.
5. `eval()` proceeds to compute the `mtcars` subsetting.

Comment: Thanks!They are very useful. I also have a followup question for you which I have to post by giving an answer to my own question. I @ your username in the answer so you know that was a response to your answer.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/58793418/1725177 xiahfyj asked how to compute the filters in a separate step than `filter()`. In general separate computations can be performed with `transmute()`. This function takes inputs and returns a data frame containing one column per input. The inputs are computed within the data frames, and within groups if there are any.

```
filter3 <- function(data, var1, var2, lower1, lower2) {
  filters <- data %>% transmute(
    filter_a = {{ var1 }} > .env$lower1,
    filter_b = {{ var2 }} > .env$lower2
  )

  data %>%
    filter(!!!unname(filters))
}
```

The data frames of evaluated filter columns can then be spliced into `filter()`. The force-splicing operator `!!!` transforms its argument to multiple inputs in the surrounding call (here, a call to `filter()`).

In the case of `filter()`, the data frame of inputs must be unnamed because there's a special check in `filter()` to throw an error for named inputs, in order to catch a common typo when the writes `a = foo` instead of `a == foo`.

We are planning to support data frame inputs in the next major version of dplyr, and auto-splice them. In that case the last step will become as simple as:

```
  data %>%
    filter(filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lionel Henry
Thanks! I do have a followup question on your example.

```
filter2 <- function(data, var1, var2, lower1, lower2) {
  data %>%
    filter(
      {{ var1 }} > .env$lower1,
      {{ var2 }} > .env$lower2
    )
}
```

What if I want something like below block? Basically I want to take what you have inside filter() out of it and store them in some variables beforehand. I know below function doesn't work. I wonder how should I edit it to make it work.

```
filter2 <- function(data, var1, var2, lower1, lower2) {
filter_a<-{{ var1 }} > .env$lower1
filter_b<-{{ var2 }} > .env$lower2
  data %>%
    filter(filter_a,filter_b)
}
```

The reason I want this is because for the purpose of my function, what's inside filter()will be dynamic. For example, I would need something like this:

```
###if both lower and upper boundary for var1 are given by the user,do below:
   filter_a<-{{ var1 }} > .env$lower1&{{ var1 }} < .env$upper1
###if only upper are given.do below:
   filter_a<-{{ var1 }} < .env$upper1
###if only lower are given, do below:
   filter_a<-{{ var1 }} > .env$lower1
```

This is also why I had so many if statements in my original long and "hard to read" question.